# truth table of equivalence relation

Tags: logic

I have found the following problem in a book:

Test the validity of the following argument:
If 6 is not even, then 5 is not prime
But 6 is even
Therefore, 5 is prime

I have made a truth table by transforming it into logical propositions like:
~p -> ~q  and p then q

and I end up with the values T/F/T/T

according to the answer of the book it is a fallacy. But logically seems that it is not, because 6 is even and 5 is a prime.

Is there any way to prove that this is a tautology?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that 5 is prime, of course.

However the *argument* does not work to show that this is the case. In order for the argument to be logically valid, it has to work *no matter what the claims it speaks about*. Logically, it is exactly the same as the argument:

> If Bob is not sad, then Alice has not broken up with him. But Bob is sad. Therefore Alice has broken up with him.

Logically that's the same argument -- we've just substituted "Bob is sad" for "6 is even" and "Alice broke up with him" for "5 is prime". Such a substitution cannot change the *logical* validity of the argument.

However, in this case it should be clearer that the argument doesn't hold water. Alice *didn't* break up with Bob; he's sad for entirely different reasons (his best friend just died).

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ := "6 is even", $q$ := "5 is prime". Suppose $(\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q)$. Further suppose that $p$. Does $q$ follow from those two assumptions? The answer is no. Consider the assignment {p := $\top$, q := $\bot$}. Since $p$ is true, $(\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q)$ is true because it's equivalent to $(p \lor \lnot q)$, and premise $p$ is also true, but $q$ is not. So the argument is invalid.